# Custom action - Modern team site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have to create custom action under standard menu(gear icon).
Using below code I am able to create custom action on classic team site.

```
$siteAction = $context.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
$siteAction.Group = "SiteActions";
$siteAction.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu";
$siteAction.Name = "Sample_CustomAction";
$siteAction.Sequence = 1000;
$siteAction.Url = $context.Url +"/_layouts/user.aspx"
$siteAction.Title = "Web Permissions";
$siteAction.Update();
$context.ExecuteQuery();
```

however, when tried the same code on modern team site, it says "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource"
I am able to access the site in browser.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs because the Customize Pages right is denied by default on the modern site collection.

To resolve this issue, we need to [Connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx) and set [**denyaddandcustomizepages**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx) of this site to false. DenyAddAndCustomizePages determines whether the Add And Customize Pages right is denied on the site collection.

```
$adminUPN="user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."

Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
set-sposite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/modernSite -denyaddandcustomizepages $false
```

After that, you can create custom site actions on the modern site using your commands.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!